Why don't leader of waring factions fight each other instead of asking the soldiers to do the fighting?
I consider the soldiers of all country to be slaves to their respective leaders. They have no option except to fight when their leaders command them to go for war. Instead of soldiers fighting each other, the leaders can fight the war directly so that innocent life of soldiers can be saved.
Now the leaders are staying in very safe zone, so they don't know the pain of killing children or pregnant woman.
Edit: How this is Off topic ? Isn't war related to Politics or is there a separate stackexchange for war ?

This makes no sense.  This has been done before in primitive Europe, single combat of leaders.  It's good for war, not for much else.  Watch Idiocracy, for example.  President Camacho would be the ideal leader in wartime.  And kinda suck at all else.  Nor is it even good at fighting wars, rational armies will just use trained soldiers.  Give these questions of yours a rest for a while.

Not my DV, but "they don't know the pain of killing children or pregnant woman". Some of them might be psychopathic enough for this not to matter to them, even if they saw it or had to do it themselves. Never mind all the rationalization about collateral damage in modern warfare with explosive weapons.

Out of curiosity, did you have a  base case for the recursion that would happen that, once a leader is defeated in combat, someone else is given the position of leader of that faction? That immediately brings to mind the idea that the war would not end any faster that way, given the recursive nature of successions.

Good idea. Me and my 3 mates are going to become an army, and challenge Joe Biden to singular combat. If I win, I get to take over the USA. I am sure Biden (and the entirety of the USA society) will agree to it.

On a less dismissive and hopefully more encouraging note.  We do have a pacifism tag going.  There is nothing wrong with being interested in approaching international affairs from that point of view.  Take a look at the existing questions, see what works.  That tag could use more activity, to be honest (measly 9 questions to date).  The intersection of pacifism and treaties/international organizations might yield some things to ask about.

"I consider the soldiers of all country to be slaves to their respective leaders." They are by definition not slaves, because they are paid. "They have no option except to fight when their leaders command them to go for war." That's how employment works. When my boss tells me "I need you to implement this new feature in my software", I have no choice but to implement it. Does that make me a "slave", even if I'm being paid £40k a year in return?

Corollary to this proposal:  let's not elect any women, ever!  Or people with disabilities, like Franklin Roosevelt.

I'm not voting to close since we don't have a specific "too naive for this world" reason but the answer to the question is "because real world is not like a Brandon Sanderson novel".

The concept of trial by combat did exist in the past, for lawsuits  and also for other conflicts. It did rely on a society which sees the leader and the country as the same (l'etat, c'est moi, as ascribed to a French king). With very few exceptions, there are no absolutist monarchies any more.

I guess MBS could win a few battles like that.

Generally speaking, soldiers are not unwilling participants, and those who are are usually poor soldiers. Soldiers are willing to risk their lives for a number of reasons:

Status and spoils of war. In ancient times particularly, joining the military was one of the quickest ways to gain social status and wealth. Looting is looked on with less favor these days, but in most places soldiers still garner a degree of respect.
Tribal, clan, or group loyalty. Most people identify with one or more groups, and recognize that sometimes the group has to act as a group — not as a collection of individuals — to achieve a goal. Acting as a group implies organization, which implies hierarchy, which implies a willingness to obey those seem as in command.
Ideology. People are often willing to risk their lives when their morals or principles are offended or threatened. Historically, many, many men have marched into wars that would otherwise not have affected them at all, merely because the group on the other side violated something the men held dear. It's worth remembering that most of the men who fought in the US Civil War were volunteers.

While personal combat between leaders or their surrogates did apparently occur historically — think the stories of  David and Goliath, or Lancelot doing battles of honor for Arthur — people understood early on that planning a battle or a war was a different skillset than fighting face-to-face. Soldiers often followed leaders on the belief that leaders had the skills to win battles. That beliefs offsets the sense of risk that going into battle entails.
